# Script that emails when duplicate is found

Tags: email, duplicates

I'm currently trying to create a script that is on a timer trigger that will email when a duplicate is found in column A, but I'm not sure how to write it to only email if the cell has a value, as currently it emails me when the cells are empty?

Comment: Are You trying ... lets show example

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You mention column A, but you don't indicate which program it is in. Are you using Excel? If you have existing code it would be very helpful to [edit] the question and include that code. You can format the code using the button with {} on it, and if you add the correct VBA tag it will even syntax highlight the code.